# Wrong subtotalizer in the column footer with IReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with totalizer from my report. In the footer from each page I need to print the sum of the records (subtotalizer), but when a page break occurs, because the historical field is very large and does not fit on this page, the sum is added with the value from next record, that will print in next page. This is wrong, should be added only the value printed on this page (records 1 - 4). I has fixed the property "Prevent"  in band "detail", to print only records that fit on the page, but occurs this problem. Someone could give me a hint? I am using groups to automatically calculate the values.

Using: IReport 5.5

Report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/njegeb3j1otr849/ireport.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ocurrs when the field text overflow, Adelar's fixed property "Prevent" in detail band

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set "Reset type" for the "subtotalizer" variable to "Page"? It works for me...

Comment: I've created a test report and it workes, here is the sample [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X1jigKEgNCelBYekxZODJJX2M/edit?usp=sharing). You have to set "Reset type" to "Page" not "Group". Check the variable properties in sample. Sample will run on any oracle DB, modify the query for other DBs.

Comment: You should have 2 variables, pageSubTotal and Total. pageSubTotal should have "Reset type" set to "Page" (like in example) and for Total set it to "Group". I don't see how you could do this with one variable.

Comment: I've modified my example, now it shows pageSubTotal and a group Total. You should probably use group_COUNT variable to hide pageSubTotal when last group row is shown to avoid having sub total and total on the same page. And when I run the example in iReport I do get the results you are looking for, subTotal on 1st page is 3 on 2nd 7 etc... [Here is the PDF I get](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X1jigKEgNCNEtyckQ5VmdhUFk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you test with my example please? To run this example you should config the classpath on ireport, adding the directory from Teste project in classpath: 

Teste\target\classes

Create a custom JRDataSource in Ireport, and set the factory class to sg3.datasource.DataSource, the static method to createDatasource.
Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8y1kfz4rl07tsc/EclipseKeplerWorkspace.zip

Comment: You were right my solution doesn't work for your problem, but yours does! Here is PDF I got with your report [link to pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X1jigKEgNCT3RwUEloZDYzNk0/edit?usp=sharing). You have a group total variable with execute time set to "Now" in page footer, so it just sums the rows that are displayed on that page from the last group on that page. Remove print when from page footer to get this output...

Comment: Sorry. I sent wrong jrxml... here are the correct dropbox.com/s/32122i10wd7uvup/Teste.jrxml Thanks for your time. I think that the problem occurs when the field text has overflow. The detail band has property "Split type" fixed to "Prevent".

Comment: There is definitely a problem with split, jasper counts a row on 1st page but it's displayed on 2nd, try a different split type. Another problem for using only a total variable is for groups that span more than 2 pages, which might be solved with one variable with "Reset type" "Group" and another with reset type "Page" and display the smaller one. GroupSubTotal would work when group spans 2 pages and PageSubTotal when it's the only group displayed on a page (ie. on 2nd page when group spans 3 pages). Hope this helps

Comment: Here is modified version of [your report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X1jigKEgNCR29ndHpNWDNyQ00/edit?usp=sharing). I've used two variables as described before and I've set split type on detail to "Immediate". Here is the [PDF output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X1jigKEgNCT3RwUEloZDYzNk0/edit?usp=sharing), it doesn't look nice but the subTotals are correct...